# Cannot read property 'show' of undefined in BoostrapVue Modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```
    <b-button
      id="show-btn"
      @click="$bvModal.show('bv-modal-example')"
    >
      Open Modal
    </b-button>
    <b-modal id="bv-modal-example">Hello From My Modal!</b-modal>
```

Vue version: 2.6.10

Installed and set Bootstrap in App.js

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

I got the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined** when I tried to open the modal.

What else should I install or set for BoostrapVue Modal to use as the instance method?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: can you paste the whole error from console? so it will be easy to find error. Apart from that did you install bootstrap and bootstrap-vue both ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some approaches that you can try to get what you want finally working.

1. Make sure whether you import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

2. If you are using a module bundler you need to try to import only specific components groups(plugins) like this.

```
import { ModalPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(ModalPlugin)
```

3. If those are not working, please please check you have both bootstrap and boostrapVue installed in your node_module.
   In order to make sure, please remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` or run `npm install bootstrap bootstrap-vue --save` in your terminal of the root directory of the project.

Hopefully, this would help you.